# Ask Looping in PHP

Tags: php, loops

Please help me.
i have code `php` like this:

```
<?php
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    for($b=1; $b<=3; $b++)  
            echo "Data ".$i." To user ".$b."<br>";
       }
?>"
```

Result:

```
Data 1 To user 1
Data 1 To user 2
Data 1 To user 3
Data 2 To user 1
Data 2 To user 2
Data 2 To user 3
Data 3 To user 1
Data 3 To user 2
Data 3 To user 3
Data 4 To user 1
Data 4 To user 2
Data 4 To user 3
Data 5 To user 1
Data 5 To user 2
Data 5 To user 3
```

How to code looping if I want  result like this:

```
Data 1 To user 1
Data 2 To user 2
Data 3 To user 3
Data 4 To user 1
Data 5 To user 2
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Hi @Rikesh:How to code single loop with result Data 1 To user 1
Data 2 To user 2
Data 3 To user 2
Data 4 To user 1
Data 5 To user 2

Comment: Learn what a foreach-loop does, check your code, smash your head on the table and then try again. These are absolute basics of not only php, but every language.

Comment: @user3300597 is there any specific reason for `Data 3 To user 2 Data 4 To user 1 Data 5 To user 2 `

Comment: @ling.s sorry i edit post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it simply using single loop,

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $j = ($i % 3) == 0 ? 3 : ($i % 3);
    echo "Data ".$i." To user ". $j ."<br>";
}
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.org/l51kMmVw)**

Answer (score 1):

add one statement checking if $b is 3 then make it to 0 and remove inner for loop. like this

```
$b= 1;
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
   echo "Data ".$i." To user ".$b."<br>\n";
   if($b == 3) {
       $b=0;
   }
   $b++;
}
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/rG8nF)